Why a project a reshape to 4x4x1024 for DCGAN?

In the paper Unsupervised Representation Learning with Deep Convolution Generative Adversarial Networks by Radford et. al. (2015), the model described projects and reshapes a 100 valued noise vector to 4x4x1024 and then to 8x8x512 and so on till the final layer outputs a 64x64x3 image as required to conform to LSUN dataset.
How was the decision made to reshape to 4x4x1024? What is the significance of these values and the number of hidden layers used?
